# Can't upvote on Meta even though I've been an SO member for more than a year?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I've had my account on Stack Overflow for more than a year now. Today, I followed a question that was migrated to Meta.

I found a few interesting comments that I wanted to upvote. But the intelligent JavaScript warned me that I was not logged in because of it being a different site.

After I logged in, it suggested I merge/associate my Meta account with my SO account. (Simply brilliant that it was just a single click. Bravo to the dev team!)

When I tried to vote up these comments from before, I was then told that I didn't have enough reputation.

What's the point of having a minimum of 15 rep and having an account for over a year when I can't upvote on the other, related, sites?

Meta Stack Overflow is user support for the main trilogy of sites and the users of such should be able to vote on the ideas and feature requests that relate to those sites.

In the real world, if you had reputation, it would stick with you wherever you went.

Comment: don't you get like 100 rep for linking your SO account with your MSO account?

Comment: @beggs. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer.

- You need 15 points to vote. That is one question with 2 votes, or one answer with 2 votes, or one question and one answer each with one vote, is it really that hard?
- If you associate your accounts and any of your accounts on the other sites have more then 200 reputation you automatically get a 100 rep boost. After a year you should have at least 200 points right?
- The requirement is there to prevent users creating sock puppet accounts and up-voting themselves to gain unnecessary reputation.
- Just because you are trusted on SO, doesn't mean you can be trusted on the other sites which cover completely different topics.

> Reputation is earned through interaction on the site, not through how long you have been a member. The latter is irrelevant if you hardly ever visit the site.

Comment: I have 166 points on stackoverflow.com, 34 less then magic number 200. Instead understanding my little desire to vote up something you advising that I should get 200 points before moving my account to meta. 

I don't want my reputations here, I don't care math that to get 100 point for free I earn 200 points or whatever. I just wanted to vote up something and talking about my unpleasant experience. 

I just wanted better experience.

Comment: You are defending reputation logic in last 2 points as it written on stone. 

1] why I wait for 1 year to act as sock puppet 

2] Trust in real world is based on relationships of trust. That is how openid works. Stackoverflow.com trust my openid provider is providing authenticating same person across login sessions.

Comment: @nexneo: You misunderstood him. He said you just have to gain 15 points here on Meta. That's all. If you do not want to invest that effort, believe me, this site will survive even without your upvote ;)

Comment: @nexneo: Seriously? I have been a SO member for a year and I have a 1000+ rep with very little interaction. Reputation is based on how much effort your willing to make, since you don't want to make any, there is no reason to complain? If you don't want to make an effort to gain the ability to vote, then it means the system is working.

Comment: @John When did I said site will not survive. It is possible that I'm being some minority as little short on magic 200 points. But last 2 points Diago mentioned doesn't make sense in this situation either.

Comment: @diago you will see users with triple of your reputation with much little efforts you have made. that doesn't mean your 1000+ indicate you doing nothing. There is nothing perfect in the world nor the point system on SO or Meta. For example, when people link their account they get 50% of reputation points but not more then 100 points. that still had same effects as now but I could have been to interact on this site better or my overall experience might have been better. Thats all

Comment: @nexneo. Why did you even ask the question, if the answer obviously does not satisfy your need? You seem to be under the impression that this is actually a problem, when in reality it is how the system works, and the reasons for this I have listed. You obviously have no understanding what reputation on SO means or how it works. I strongly suggest you read the FAQ in detail. The fact is that you need 15 reputation points to vote, and on every site you start fresh, with a 100 point rep bonus if you have 200 or more rep points on any other site, and your rep on SO does not matter on any other.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation limits, which are similar but not the same on meta, function to keep the anonymous google user from being able to dump all over the site.  You need to invest a (very) little to get voting privileges on meta, just like you do on all of the other sites to be trusted to vote on other people questions and answers.  Essentially, the sites says you have to care a little to get to participate more.  The more you care -- as shown by participation in asking and answering questions, especially with good questions/answers -- the more you get to do. I think this is a perfectly reasonable requirement, especially since the bar is so low for what you want to do.  Having been on SO for more than a year, I would have expected you to know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-pollination of rep.  SO and MSO are different communities and you need to earn the respect of the community to enjoy the perks you reference.

Comment: Technically there's a little, via the account linking bonus.

Comment: But link your account after you get 200 points.

Comment: @Dav, fair enough... a little.  Like being a friend of a friend :-)